# LINK2001 When Building Visual Studio Project, BGSLIbrary, where is Linker in v2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build the BGSLibrary for Windows 10, cmake 3.9, with python support, built with opencv 3.1 and boost 1.64.0 with Visual Studio Community 2017.

Can someone more familiar with Visual Studio interpret this error for me. The c++ seems to compile great, but then project solution fails. It starts by building all the .obj files

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86\Lib.exe /OUT:"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\bgslibrary\build\libbgs.lib" /NOLOGO  /machine:X86 libbgs.dir\Release\AdaptiveBackgroundLearning.obj
2>libbgs.dir\Release\AdaptiveSelectiveBackgroundLearning.obj
2>libbgs.dir\Release\CodeBook.obj
2>libbgs.dir\Release\DPAdaptiveMedian.obj
2>libbgs.dir\Release\DPEigenbackground.obj
```

The general error reads.

```
5>libbgs.lib(LBSP.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::Feature2D::read(class cv::FileNode const &)" (?read@Feature2D@cv@@UAEXABVFileNode@2@@Z) referenced in function "[thunk]:public: virtual void __thiscall cv::Feature2D::read`vtordisp{4294967292,0}' (class cv::FileNode const &)" (?read@Feature2D@cv@@$4PPPPPPPM@A@AEXABVFileNode@2@@Z)
```

But the file LBSP.obj compiled fine just 100 lines earlier? I can see it here.

[image]

This file was created during the build, why can't it link? Where do I need to add this dir?

I'm reading other SO questions that this error may mean I need to add additional paths, which was done pre-VS2017 by going to PROPERTIES->LINKER->ADDITIONAL DEPENDENCIES. I don't see this option or structure anymore.

[image]

```
3>C:\Users\Ben\Documents\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(894)
```

Comment: `PROPERTIES->LINKER->ADDITIONAL DEPENDENCIES` is still there, you just need to actually look at the properties of a C++ project file, not some generic non-c++ project like the CMake "ALL_BUILD" project. Look at the properties of the libbgs project or the bgs_demo ones if libbgs is build as a static lib.

Comment: Although if this project was generated with CMake you should probably not touch the compiler settings in the IDE since regeneration would replace the values you changed. With that said I have not tested the CMake support in Visual Studio 2017 so not sure if this is still an issue.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm. More broadly, can you give me a couple sentences on what is happening here? Is it that it compiles a .obj file, but then doesn't know where it is when it builds the solution? I see an option under linker "Link Library Dependencies" which reads "Specifies whether of not library outputs from project dependencies are automatically linked in" Should I turn that to yes.

Comment: I think either CMake did not find a required library (which you may be able to fix in cmake-gui) or the CMakeLists.txt you are using has a bug.

Comment: Oh, totally different, I thought this would be a Visual Studio error. Let me go back and think about Cmake.

Answer (score 0):

This was a Cmake path error, not a Visual Studio error. Adding OpenCV/bin to path solved this.